# Determining integral of radius of curvature teardrop

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Consider two line pieces of same size that are connected at one end and at the other end they are connected by a circle segment. The total length, so circle segment and straight parts together have length $L$. I have to determine the following (approximate) integral and minimize it with respect to the apex angle $\alpha$ (angle between straight lines)

$$H=\int^L_0 \frac{1}{R(s)^2} ds$$

where $R(s)$ is the radius of curvature. I know that for the circular part it holds true that this is constant. And I thought that the straight parts do not contribute. However, this idea does not yield the result $\alpha+\pi=\tan(\alpha)$ for the $\alpha$ that minimizes $H$. What goes wrong in my calculations?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the connecting points of the circular arc to the straight parts are "smooth" (the tangent is continuous), right? That is, for larger apex $\alpha$ the arc has a large angle span (but small curvature). For small apex $\alpha$ the circular arc approaches a semi-circle (which is relatively smaller angle span) but with larger curvature. Is this the right picture?

Comment: Yes I think that is true

Comment: If we're on the same page, then the circular arc length depends on $\alpha$, and the integration limit is not $L$. Would you like to try the new calculation yourself first?

Comment: Yes I did but I only get a term with $\alpha r$ with $r$ the radius of curvature. But I don't see where the other terms come from. Could you elaborate a bit using a equation to start with?

Comment: Let me type up a post. It will take some time to make a diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}\renewcommand{\paren}[1]{ \Bigl( #1 \Bigr) }$Following the given settings, denote the length of each straight segment as $\ell$, the apex angle as $\alpha$, and the radius of the circular arc as $r$. From the diagram we have:
$$r = \ell \tan\frac{\alpha}2 \qquad \text{or} \quad\ell = \frac{r}t \qquad \text{where} \quad t \equiv \tan\frac{\alpha}2~.$$

Also from the diagram are the angles sizes, making the total length (straight plus arc)
$$L=2\ell + r(\pi+\alpha) \implies  r \paren{ \frac2t + \pi + \alpha} = L~.$$
[image]
The contribution from the straight segments is zero (radius of curvature $R(s)$ is infinite), and for the circular part it is $R(s) = r$, constant over the entire arc length of $r(\pi+\alpha)$:

$$H=\int^L_0 \frac{1}{R(s)^2} \dd{s} = \int^{r(\pi+\alpha)}_0 \frac1{r^2} \dd{s} = \frac{\pi+\alpha}{r} = \frac1L(\pi+\alpha)\paren{\pi+\alpha+\frac2t} \\
\begin{aligned}
\implies \frac{ \dd{H} }{ \dd{\alpha } } &\propto \frac{ \dd{} }{ \dd{\alpha } } \left( (\pi+\alpha)^2 + (\pi+\alpha) \frac2t \right) \quad\small\text{, written this way for convenience at the end}\\
&= 2(\pi+\alpha) + \frac2t + (\pi+\alpha) \frac{-2}{t^2} \frac{ \dd{t} }{ \dd{\alpha } } \qquad \text{, note that} \quad \frac{ \dd{t} }{ \dd{\alpha } } = \frac{1+t^2}2 \\
&= 2 \paren{\pi+\alpha + \frac1t} - (\pi+\alpha)\frac{1+t^2}{t^2}
\end{aligned}$$

The optimal angle will be at $dH/d\alpha = 0$ (with considerably more effort $d^2 H/d\alpha^2 > 0$ can be double checked).

\begin{align}
2 \paren{\pi+\alpha + \frac1t} &= (\pi+\alpha)\frac{1+t^2}{t^2} \\
1 + \frac1{ (\pi+\alpha) \cdot t} &= \frac{1+t^2}{2t^2} \\
\frac1{ (\pi+\alpha) t} &= \frac{1-t^2}{2t^2} \\
\pi+\alpha &= \frac{2t}{1-t^2} = \tan\alpha  
\end{align}
The last line ends with the well-known identity for tangent-of-half-angle.

Comment: Quite helpful. Thank you for the rigorous answer!